# Need advice to collect data from other table

Tags: sql-server

I'm developing app to control material. I have two tables, **table A** storing information of all items with column `Date` record changing status by time. I want to design **Table B** collecting data from table A by days of month, this table has columns `Col1, Col2...Col30` implying days of a month, column `Date` of table A will link to suitable "Col" of table B by day

Detail as below:

Table A storing information by date

```
+------+-----+----------+
| Code | Qty |   Date   |
+------+-----+----------+
| A1   |  10 | -04-18 |
| A2   |  12 | -04-18 |
| A3   |   5 | -04-18 |
| A1   |   5 | -04-18 |
| A2   |   1 | -04-18 |
+------+-----+----------+
```

Image URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Sxhp.jpg

Table B, collecting data from table B:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Code |  |   |  |  |   |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| A1   |      |   10 |      |      |    5 |
| A2   |   12 |    1 |      |      |      |
| A3   |      |      |      |      |    5 |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Image URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtjRi.jpg

If look up all rows of table A and insert to table B spending resource of computer

I'm looking for the way to do it but reducing computer's resource consuming

Please support
Thank you with appreciation

Comment: What you've got so far? And why do you think you need the table `B` in that format? You could easily query `A` with proper aggregation and by extracting the day with `DATEPART()` but you'll get it a format transposed (columns = rows, rows = column) to that of `B`.

Comment: Thank you for your support. But i want to update data to table B format(table B storing not only data of table A,  i have many table need to update to table B).  Transpose only show data for one table.

Comment: If you are implying days of a month, there should be Col31 columns, right?

Comment: Thank you @D T,  Col[i] should be Col1, Col2... Col31

Comment: Tables in a database are not a good means for end user display.  The presentation to the user is the job of the application.